# C# - socket permission error on remote MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, uwp

My UWP works fine with MySQL on the localhost. When connecting to the copy of this DB on a remote computer, I get the error (Access denied because of socket permissions). But I can connect remotely using the MySQL-shell! So it is not the connection itself then and it's not the connection string. It is a riddle to me.

I checked the TCP-connections if there were multiple connections. This does not happen.

Comment: If you have correct configuration, this should work. We ever tried to connect a remote MySQL from UWP app with successful. So please detail your issue with some environment information. For example the UWP app target version. And please tried to enable the `Internet`, `Private Networks` capabilities in UWP app.

Comment: For  "if there were multiple connections. This does not happen",  could you please tell what this mean?  Can you connect successfully?

Comment: Glad to hear that, I will transfer the comment as an answer.

Comment: Sunteen Wu, you saved me! "Privat Network" under Capabilites were unchecked. For those who are as new as I am: You can find it when you open the "Package.appxmanifest" in the "Solution Explorer" far down  and open the "Capabilities"-list there. What a relieve you gave me, Sunteen Wu! Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have correct configuration, this should work. We ever tried to connect a remote MySQL from UWP app with successful.

So please e tried to enable the following capabilities in UWP app:

- Internet(Client)
- Internet(Client & Server)
- Private Networks (Client & Server)

More details please reference [App capability declarations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations).

Comment: Thanks again - and please contact me!